# Firebase Foreground Push Notification

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

Hey I'm building a Flutter app, I'm using firebase as my backend. I tried out push notifications from firebase cloud messaging. The notifications are only received only when the app is in background. I sent the notification from firebase console. But when the app is open the notifications don't appear. Can anyone help me out ? and yes I got the correct tokens and pasted them correctly in the console before sending the test notification.